# Где находятся jar-файлы в IntelliJ IDEA при запуске Tomcat, если war ехploded?

Tags: intellij-idea, tomcat

Пробую запустить приложение на `tomee`. `Artifact war` в режиме `exploded`, все jar-файлы стер из папки lib - {project location}/target/{project name}/WEB-INF/lib. Но все равно приложение продолжает запускаться. Остается вопрос где находятся jar-файлы приложения при запуске его на `tomcat`.

Comment: А вы строите war при помощи maven?

Comment: Проект собирается при помощи maven.
В результате все артифакты находятся в каталоге project location}/target/{project name}. {project location}/target/{project name}/WEB-INF/lib не видны для tomcata. Например программа продолжает запускаться даже если мы стираем все jar файлы из каталога {project location}/target/{project name}/WEB-INF/lib
Вопрос куда смотрит tomcat для нахождения jar файлов?
К стати мы используем tomee (tomcat8).

Comment: Я посмотрел в настройки у себя, и кажется, что IDEA заставляет его смотреть в мавен репозиторий. Посмотрите на артефакты в идеи, там видно, откуда берутся зависимости для lib. Хотя я не уверен. А вас не устраивает ответ который дал Сергей?

Comment: Спасибо Вам за комментарий, в принципе ответ Сергея содержит информацию для решения данного вопроса. Я бы хотела начислить ему балл за ответ но к сожалению я немогу войти на ru.stackoverflow? Хотя почему-то могу комментировать вопроссы я могу (нонсонс?). Если бы Вы могли пожалуйста начислите Сергею дополнительный балл. Заранее спасибо Вам!

Comment: Это потому что вы не зарегистрированы. Если у вас уже есть аккаунт, я могу позвать контент менеджера, он поможет вам объединить аккаунты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При таком запуске из самой IDEA файлы проекта и библиотек остаются на своих местах.

IDEA формирует очень длинную строку запуска в которой определяет:

- каталог приложения - в нашем случае это $PROJECT_DIR$/build/classes/artifacts/имя_атeфакта
- список библиотек пути которых, берутся из настроек проекта. Если вы выбрали их хранение в каталоге, то в $PROJECT_DIR$/.idea/libraries можно увидеть данные по всем библиотекам проекта.

Все это вставляется в строку запуска `java -jar ...`.

Comment: Спасибо Вам за ответ!

Answer (score -1):

Приложение после установки размещается в `${TOMCAT_HOME}/webapps`. Соответственно все библиотеки приложения лежат в `${TOMCAT_HOME}/webapps/твоё_приложение/WEB-INF/lib`.